# Application Does Not Start in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I recently installed a new 60GB SSD as my primary hard drive and re-installed Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.  I then installed [SSD Fresh from Abelssoft](http://www.abelssoft.net/ssdfresh.php) to optimize Windows to run on the SSD.  It seemed to install okay, but when I try to run the utility, its splash screen appears briefly before it quietly closes.  No errors are displayed; the utility just fails to launch.  I have run SSD Fresh on another SSD-equipped Windows 7 Pro x64 computer in the past without any problems.

Does anyone know what might be preventing the program from running?  I tried running `sfc /scannow` from the command line (with administrator privileges), shutting down the Spybot Resident, and disabling the firewall and virus scanner.  I also tried running the tool as administrator; I even tried reinstalling it, running the installer as administrator.  No luck.

Every time I try to launch the program the Event Viewer logs this same set of errors:

```
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:44 PM    Application Error   1000    (100)

Faulting application name: SSDFresh.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4f2a45d8
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000007ff0016dbba
Faulting process id: 0x994
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd11fd9fe978df
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\SSD Fresh\SSDFresh.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: dfeed551-7df0-11e1-a2c7-002522c47ec0

Error   4/2/2012 11:35:43 PM    .NET Runtime    1026    None

Application: SSDFresh.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
   at AbBugReporter.BugForm.InitLanguage()
   at AbBugReporter.BugForm..ctor(AbFlexTrans.LanguageInfo, AbBugReporter.BugReportManager, Boolean)
   at AbBugReporter.BugReportManager.Show(System.Exception)
   at SSDFresh.App.App_DispatcherUnhandledException(System.Object, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CatchException(System.Exception)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at SSDFresh.App.Main()

Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None

Activation context generation failed for "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe.Config" on line 0. Invalid Xml syntax.

Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
Error   4/2/2012 11:35:39 PM    SideBySide  59  None
```

For those who are interested, here is my system configuration:

- [ASRock M3A770DE AM3 AMD 770 ATX AMD Motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157176R)
- [AMD Athlon II X3 455 Rana 3.3GHz Socket AM3 95W Triple-Core Desktop Processor ADX455WFGMBOX](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103911)
- [G.SKILL Value Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1333 (PC3 10600) Desktop Memory Model F3-10600CL9D-8GBNT](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231422)
- [Mushkin Enhanced Chronos Deluxe MKNSSDCR60GB-DX 2.5" 60GB SATA III Synchronous MLC Internal Solid State Drive (SSD)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820226246) (Primary/Boot HD)
- [Western Digital Caviar Blue RFHWD1600AAJS 160GB 7200 RPM SATA 3.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive -Bare Drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136590) (Secondary HD)
- [Sony Optiarc CD/DVD Burner Black SATA Model AD-7261S-0B LightScribe Support](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16827118040)
- [RAIDMAX RX-850AE 850W ATX12V v2.3 / EPS12V SLI Certified CrossFire Ready 80 PLUS GOLD Certified Modular Active PFC Power Supply](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817152043)
- [ASUS HD7850-DC2-2GD5 Radeon HD 7850 2GB 256-bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 x16 HDCP Ready CrossFireX Support Video Card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814121623)
- [Asus ML228H 21.5" Full HD LED BackLight LED Monitor Slim Design](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824236099) (x3)

Comment: What are the details provided in those SideBySide events?  They usually tell you what the assembly it is trying to use (and the version it's expecting).  Often it's non-existent/wrong version/corrupted runtime libraries (like the [VC++ Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14632)), but you'll need to tell us what it's telling you it's looking for before we can tell you what you need. :)

Comment: I'll post the error details when I get home this evening, so please stay tuned...

Comment: Fresh installation of the Windows 7 does not require any tweaks for ssd.

Comment: I've added the error details.

Comment: @crea7: Check out this post on gHacks: http://www.ghacks.net/2011/10/15/ssd-fresh-optimize-windows-for-ssd-usage/

Comment: Windows 7 will disable all these services. Except the important ones like "Windows event logging" etc. To disable search indexing you should open Services panel and disable indexing service. To disable timestamp feature use this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940846(v=winembedded.5).aspx). Other functions is important for your system (like system restore and event log).

Comment: There is obviously a problem, or the application wouldn't have crashed on launch.  Let's please address that.  Some posts I've read elsewhere seem to indicate that I may need to (re)install the x86 and/or x64 C++ redistributable.  What do you think?

Comment: "Exception code: 0xc0000005" is an access denied error.

Comment: @techie007: Do you have any ideas as to why it would be generating an accessed denied error, even when I'm running the application with administrator privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to contact the company who wrote the program?  Jim's suggestion about the C++ redistrubutable is great except the program is CLEARLY written in C#.  This is clearly a bug in the application itself.

It might not be solvable by you, it might have to be solved by the company, who wrote the program.

Comment: Your answer was closest to the mark.  I did a repair of the .NET Framework 4 Client, and the problem seems to have resolved itself.  I can only assume that the framework somehow became corrupted.
Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features, select Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, click Uninstall/Change.  From the Maintenance screen that opens, choose "Repair .NET Framework 4 Client Project to its original state."

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas on what you could try :

1. Look for a missing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package (examining the manifest embedded in csc.exe or present in its folder will indicate the required version)
2. Using the [System Update Readiness Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) sometimes solves problems
3. Turn off [Hardware DEP](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-Data-Execution-Prevention-settings) for csc.exe

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  These were good suggestions, which I'll be sure to keep in mind for future debugging.